# It's ok to study the C++ from a book that only support the 1998 version of standard?

Tags: c++, books

I have this big book that basically covers all the main aspects of the C++, the problem is that is pretty old according to the C++ standards of today, it's ok to use it?

Comment: Far more important than which language it uses as baseline is whether it teaches using that language in ways that are now considered good. Writing "C/C++11" is worse than writing "Modern C++98".

Comment: It'd probably help if you named the actual book.

Comment: @Caleb it's an italian book from a university professor, i do not think you know, anyway [this](http://books.google.it/books?id=2HvIPAAACAAJ&dq=da+c%2B%2B+a+uml&hl=it&sa=X&ei=qzXuT-LiHseUsgady9jyDg&ved=0CDcQ6AEwAA) is the book and the main topics are C++ and UML.

Comment: @delan C/C++ isn't a language, and C/C++11 definitely isn't a language. There is language that is called C and there is a language called C++ which in most cases is a superset of C, but not in all cases. They are two different languages. Saying C/C++ is like saying Java/C#.

Comment: @JarrodRoberson: You missed delnan's point. Of course there is a language *C/C++* aka *C with classes* and there is another language *Modern C++*.

Comment: @honk `C/C++` is **not** a language, period. Show me the language specification for something called `C/C++`? There isn't one, and using the `C/C++` term shows a lack of comprehension of the sublets of both languages and environments.

Comment: There is no such thing as `C/C++`. It exists only in your mind.

Comment: In short - Yes, if you support that version in legacy system.

Comment: @JarrodRoberson the term is clearly being used to mean something other than a formally specified language (its even is quotes to emphasis this) contrary to popular belief "C/C++", while not a formally specified language is a useful label for either the common subset of C and C++ or, as its used here I think, "in the style of someone who doesn't get the subtleties of C and C++"

Comment: Plain and simply put `C/C++` on a resume and it will get tossed in the trash quicker than you can ever imagine by anyone with any technical acume at all! It isn't a real term, it shows ignorance and lack of comprehension of both `C` and `C++`. Imagine if you saw `VB6/C#` or `Java/.Net` doesn't make anymore sense than `C/C++`, and shows confusion at best and total lack of comprehension at worst. Go ahead and use that term for whatever *you* think it means, everyone else thinks it means ignorance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's fine to use it. You won't get the most up-to-the-minute information, but the large majority of C++ is the same language that it was in 1998. If you're just learning the basics, go right ahead. Just keep in mind that there have been some refinements, and look for resources that explain the differences so that you're aware of them.

Here are a few of those resources:

- [Wikipedia article on C++11](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C++11) summarizes the new features in C++11.
- [AT&T's C++11 FAQ](//www.stroustrup.com/C++11FAQ.html)
- [Bjarne Stroustrup's C++ FAQ](//www.stroustrup.com/bs_faq.html), which covers a lot of C++ stuff

Comment: Not to mention that not every development shop is using the most recent compiler stack on their platform, so by sticking to "old" patterns you can work on a larger number of codebases and environments.

Comment: That's not true at all. C++11 is a major gamechanger in many areas.

Comment: @DeadMG I'm not saying that the differences aren't important, but to someone just learning C++, there's plenty to learn that stays the same. [Stroustrup himself wrote](http://www.research.att.com/~bs/bs_faq.html#4th) that although he's working on a 4th edition of his book, "...it is important that The C++ Programming Language (3rd Edition) describes Standard C++, its standard library, and the techniques they support... It is not suddenly going to be outdated. The billions of lines of C++ will still mostly be C++98 and will still work with C++11 compilers."

Comment: Not to mention that when C++98 was out most compilers and therefore books did not support exceptions or mention the STL.

Comment: @LokiAstari The OP said his book covers the C++98 standard, and that certainly includes exceptions. Stroustrup's *The C++ Programming Language, 3rd ed.* was published in '97 but includes both exceptions and the STL. I'm dubious that "most" books on C++98 don't cover those things -- I have a few books from that era and all cover both.

Comment: If the learning is to learn the syntax, go ahead, with caution, the syntax is substantially the same with notable exceptions compared to C++11 easy to find and relatively small. I am in the boat of wanting to re-learn C++ after about 18 years away from it. As I see it, C++ today is syntactically the same (To practical purposes), C++11 a little different, But I have to  learn to write "C++11 programs", not "C with Classes C++" or "C++ circa 2000"

Comment: @Caleb: Yep the "The C++ Programming Language, 3rd" did have them. But it is a reference on the whole language (and thus you expect it to have all the stuff). It's not a book you learn from. Sure there will be exceptions to the rule. But books that taught the language used the compilers of the era and they did not support exceptions (the compilers) and the STL was still very buggy in those days (remember STLPort) as a result books even stayed cleared of that subject.

Answer (score 10):

C++11 is a pretty big deal- not to mention that *many* books back in 98 taught C with Classes, rather than C++. I'd look for something newer. We have a question on Stack Overflow which supplies recommendations for books worth possessing.

Edit: Of course, there are also many new C++ techniques which simply did not exist previously, especially where templates are concerned, and there are some idioms which are no longer, like checking for self-assignment, not to mention global changes in the software industry like pushes for parallelism.

Comment: That's the question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list

Comment: Note that the OP never actually said that the book is from 1998 - only that it is about the 98 version of the language.

Comment: @sepp2k - The advice is the same.  The C98 specification is outdated.  It is fine if that is what you need to use, but if you have a choice, learn the current specification and the differences between them.

Comment: @DeadMG Is checking for self assignment universally gone? Why?

Comment: @Dave: Because self-assignment is actually insanely rare, but you pay the cost of the check. Copying or moving the object on the rare scenario when you do self-assign is less cost overall.

Answer (score 2):

It's probably better to learn the old version first:

- It may be a while before C++11 is fully supported by the latest version of your favorite compiler.  Or the compiler your particular project requires you to use.
- Code written before C++11 won't use it.  It may be a while (as in, "possibly never") before any given project migrates to C++11.
- In order to understand the reasoning behind the design of C++11, it is probably best to understand the original form of the language.

At any rate, if you don't learn the old version first, you may have a hard time figuring out how to write for any system that doesn't fully support the new one.  For that matter, I would recommend learning C first, before learning the old version of C++:  it will save you many agonizing moments of "why the hell did they do it like *that*?"

Comment: -1 - why the recommendation to learn C? the question only mentions c++

Comment: actually nevermind, I see you said so you don't question the reason. Although I disagree I don't think it warrants a downvote, removed. edit: sorry can't remove it now

Comment: Yes it may be worth learning C++03. But it is **definitively** not worth learning C++98 (that is dead). Even books written in the early 2000's are going to be pretty horrible for learning C++03 from as the way the language is used has drastically changed. I would recommend not learning `C` as a stepping stone to learn C++  (learn it as its own language) but it apart from the underlying basic syntax they have nothing in common. What is good practice in C may not be good practice in C++.

Answer (score 2):

I am going to advocate learning C++11, not older versions. It's true that the large majority of the language syntax and semantics will be the same and it's true that there's virtually *no* C++ 11 codebases in the roughly gazillion lines out in the wild. So, yes, it's true that you're essentially learning a new and not-yet-common dialect and that may be a disadvantage if you are quickly charged with doing something with an older dialect.

But the new dialect is *better* and *simpler*. The problem, I think, is that when you *do* go and deal with an older codebase, you may be confused by "Why didn't they just use...?" thoughts. But the flipside is that if you learn an old dialect, as a beginner you are poorly prepared to know "Oh, okay, this template thing is replaced by a much simpler lambda thing..."  and you can find yourself dealing with some really hairy-looking code.

It's true that compiler support is still patchy, but I think everyone has `auto` and lambdas and range-based `for` and support `shared_ptr`/`unique_ptr`/`weak_ptr`. So there's a lot of *really* big wins that are widely available.

(It's true, though, that if you're just using a book, you probably *won't* be exposed to the full glorious melange of idioms you see in a legacy codebase.)

Answer (score 2):

The book itself isn't bad, but it is not a "language" book, but much more a "software engineering book".

It should not be used to learn a "language" but to learn "design techniques". The language is just a tool to implement the samples.

That said, we have to consider that in '98 C++ had a flawed template support and that many techniques where not been discovered/invented yet.

You must hence be conscious about some potential risks:

1. The author don't speach about a technique because not yet available. This is information incompleteness, you can fill-up with a further read. Not bad by itself... but why not start with a more recent reading?
2. The author is not (yet) aware of a potential problem a technique is teaching may have (because it has been discovered later). A bit more dangerous: if you don't fill this gap, you may be in troubles other are already away from.
3. The author is aware of certain problems and teach you techniques to avoid/solve them. May be now there are more effective/proper ways to avoid/solve those problems, making those techniques unnecessary overhead.

Moral: when talking about C++, books that predate 2003 should not be anymore considered.

Comment: can you give me some good title? Which version of the standard you can consider a good starting point?

Comment: There is a question on SO that covers suggestions on C++ books.

Comment: I have to disagree about the date. Alexandrescu's *Modern C++ Design* from 2001 is considered the definitive book on template-metaprogramming. Of course, when it was written, most compilers didn't even support templates well enough to use everything in it.

Comment: @DirkHolsopple: One of the things I've leaned in 30+ more year of experience is "never use the word "definitive".   Andrei's work *was* truly the predecessor of template metaprogramming. It is certaily good about the concepts, but it requires a review about the samples, at least because C++11 syntax can greatly simplify many of them (He make a lot of mortal-jumps to allow varadic template surrogates not anymore necessary, for example!). The point is to be aware of it. You can study Andrei's techniques, of course, but I would not recommend them as **today's** best practices...

Comment: ... Although it is certainly true that many of *today's best practices* derives from Andrei's studies and publications